# Tag for [Ownership] appears to be too broad

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

I just came across the tag of [ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ownership) in my edit queue, being applied for a question about Rust. It appears the tag is a little too broad and we could do with implementing separate tags (E.g. Rust-Ownership) instead or removing them from the questions?

The tag also has no wiki currently associated with it, giving users no guidance on what the tag should be used for

At the moment, ownership is [being used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ownership) for ownership of files, [Rust Ownership](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ownership.html), and  [C++ ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13852710/single-vs-shared-ownership-meaning)

Comment: -1 for not using a title like "Stack Overflow should no longer have [ownership] of this tag"... Just kidding (but I am a little sad you didn't include a pun). Anyways, I agree - this tag should be burned.

Comment: "Disown [ownership]"?

Comment: "Should we [own](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/own "Definition 6") [ownership]?"

Comment: Apologies @Jojodmo, my pun knowledge is pretty bad, I guess you could say it's punishable.... *ba dum tss*

Comment: "Diss [ownership]  (oh snap)"?

Comment: "Abandon [ownership]!"

Answer (score 2):

Ownership is an important concept in C, C++, and Rust, but in my experience, Rust talks about the *concept* of ownership a lot more - it's the [title of an entire chapter of the official book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ownership.html)! However, I would argue that the underlying principles are the same across the languages.

Because the concept is the same, I would recommend that <s>the existing [ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ownership) be used for this concept in these languages (and perhaps others?)</s> **we retag these under the existing [ownership-semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ownership-semantics)** and the filesystem-related changes graduate to their own tag. Questions with [ownership](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ownership) would still have language-specific tags to further refine them.

<s>Obviously, a useful tag wiki should be created in this case ^_^</s> [ownership-semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ownership-semantics) has an existing wiki.

Comment: The biggest issue I have at the moment is the lack of Wiki, there is no clear definition on how the [tag:ownership] should be used. If that could be cleared it, it would be nice. Though I do feel people will still use the  [tag:ownership] for the wrong things and there is no clear way to say it should be used one way or the other, without people checking the wiki (Which we all know, everyone does that....). Maybe the [tag:ownership] should be removed and instead we create a file-ownership and a another tag for the c++ and rust ownership concept?

Comment: @Draken *people will still use the ownership for the wrong things and there is no clear way to say it should be used one way or the other, without people checking the wiki* — isn't that true for an overwhelming number of tags? It doesn't seem like that by itself should be a black mark.

Comment: @Draken please see my update. While preparing a tag wiki for [tag:ownership], I found [tag:ownership-semantics], which seems reasonable to use.