# I want to create the tag gsl-owner

Tags: discussion, support, tags

The C++ core guidelines support library (a.k.a. GSL) has a template names `owner<>` for indicating pointer ownership. I want to create the tag [gsl-owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gsl-owner) (as opposed to just `owner`). However, there already is a tag named [gsl-owners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gsl-owners)... UI says "raise this on meta", so here.

Comment: [This question and answer combo are talking about the issue with ownwership tag as well.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334908/tag-for-ownership-appears-to-be-too-broad) You might want to use [Ownership-semantics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ownership-semantics) instead

Answer (score 0):

I really don't think there is a need for such a specific tag. We already have a tag for the C++ core guidelines [cpp-core-guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cpp-core-guidelines), which includes the guideline support library. We don't need a separate tag for the GSL or for every individual element of the GSL.